# Invalid Access Token in AWS Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, async-await, alexa-skills-kit

Here is my code which I used for fetching the profile details using alexa skills but getting 401 issue along with below error

```
const GetMyEmailIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetMyEmailIntent'
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
            var apiaccessToken = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.apiAaccessToken;
            var options = {
                host :  baseURL,
                path : '/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email',

                Accept: 'application/json',
                method : 'GET',
                 headers:{
                    auth: 'Bearer ' + apiaccessToken            
                 }
            }            
          // making the https get call
            var getReq = https.request(options, function(res) {
                res.on('data', function(data) {
                });
            });

            //end the request
            getReq.end();
            getReq.on('error', function(err){
            }); 

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      getEmail(apiaccessToken => {
        var speechText = 'Your accessToken fetched successfully';
        resolve(
          handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse()
        );
      });
    });

  }
};
```

The error message that results is a 401 error that states that it's unable to determine the domain name. It also says I have an invalid token. However, I have provided the auth bearer token as a header inside the options object. I'm doing string concatenation to appear Bearer to the api token that comes in on the handlerInput.

```
2019-07-24T13:12:17.200Z    c3b8254b-e773-43db-8a96-0ff0aeea1f5e    Error handled: Unable to determine the domain name
2019-07-24T13:12:17.418Z    c3b8254b-e773-43db-8a96-0ff0aeea1f5e    
status code:============= 401
2019-07-24T13:12:17.419Z    c3b8254b-e773-43db-8a96-0ff0aeea1f5e    
INSIDE res.on:============= { code: 'ACCESS_DENIED', message: 'Invalid token' }
END RequestId: c3b8254b-e773-43db-8a96-0ff0aeea1f5e
```

Comment: Header should be "Authorization" not "auth"

Comment: Also move "Accept" into headers object.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same. The only change I made is fetching the API endpoint from Context rather than hardcoding it.Below is the code that worked for me.

```
var profileAccessToken = 'Bearer ' + this.event.context.System.apiAccessToken;
var profileApiEndpoint = this.event.context.System.apiEndpoint;
const options = {
  Host: profileApiEndpoint,
  Accept: 'application/json',
  Authorization: profileAccessToken
};

console.log(options);
var requestURLProfileEmail = profileApiEndpoint + "/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email";
console.log(requestURLProfile);
https.get(requestURLProfileEmail, options, (resp) => {
  let data = '';
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Response profile info request-->' + data);
  });
}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  this.emit(":tell", "There was an error processing your request.Please try again.");
});
```